# harp.gl: properly scaling georeferenced 3D geometries (in metres) added through three.js

Tags: here-api, harp.gl

I have a 3D model in a coordinate system that is defined in metres. The coordinates have been transformed to have the centre of the bounding box of the model as the origin. A vertex with the coordinates (1, 0, 0) would thus lie 1 metre from the origin.

When trying to add the geometries to the map, with the actual latitude/longitude of the origin as geoPosition, they don't get placed at the exact location and appear smaller than they are. How could I solve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can center the map at whatever point you would like in the world with this method:

```
map.setCameraGeolocationAndZoom(
   //Singapore coordinates and zoom level 16:
   new harp.GeoCoordinates(1.278676, 103.850216), 16 
);
```

You can specify the projection type in the MapView's constructor.

To implement a globe projection:

```
const map = new harp.MapView({
   canvas,
   theme: "https://unpkg.com/@here/harp-map-theme@latest/resources/berlin_tilezen_base_globe.json",
   projection: harp.sphereProjection,
   //For tile cache optimization:
   maxVisibleDataSourceTiles: 40, 
   tileCacheSize: 100
});
//And set it to a view where you can see the whole world:
map.setCameraGeolocationAndZoom(new harp.GeoCoordinates(1.278676, 103.850216), 4);
```

Please refer documentation for more reference:

https://developer.here.com/tutorials/harpgl/#modify-the-map